# Understanding set()

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Reading the python docs I come to set().  At the moment my understanding is considering that set is a term used to define instances of frozenset, list, tuple, and dict classes.

Firstly, is this correct?

Secondly, could anyone supply further information that may expose set()'s place in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Python `set` is the same concept as a [mathematical set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_set).

Sets contain only unique elements and are an *unordered* collection, there is no such thing as the "first" or "second" element in a set.

```
>>> a = set()
>>> a.add(1)
>>> a
set([1])
>>> a.add(1)
>>> a
set([1])
```

You cannot index a set:

```
>>> a[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Sets can be iterated, but the order of iteration is not defined and should never be relied upon:

```
>>> for x in {1, 3, 2}:
...     print x
...
1
2
3
```

`dict` and `list` are not sets, you might be confused by the fact that the set documentation appears in the same area of the Python docs as the other collections; while a `frozenset` is a particular type of `set`.

Comment: the order is not essential attribute of a set (default hashtable-based set in Python is unordered) There could be an ordered set: it is a set and it is ordered (tree-based set in C++ is ordered).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian that might be an implementation detail of some particular implementations of a Set datatype, but as far as the mathematical set is, `{1 2 3}` and `{3 2 1}` are the same set.

Comment: I know. Programming is a separate discipline built on top of math (among other thing). Math doesn't care that a find operation on a set is `O(log n)` according to C++ standard, programmers do. Math doesn't care that the worst case for the find operation on a set in Python is `O(n)` (being O(1) in ordinary circumstances), programmers do.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to matt b's answer, from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) --

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference.